# Не переводит части шаблона при переходе на украинский язык

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, локализация

Когда выбираю украинский язык в настройках Wordpress, то частично текст в теме шаблона остаётся на английском языке, например на странице Мой Аккаунт, а также на странице завершения заказа:

В папочке \wp-content\languages\plugins есть файлики woocommerce-uk.mo и woocommerce-uk.po

Но всё равно текст частично отображается на английском языке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Точно также и на странице завершения заказа, некоторые элементы не переводятся и остаются на английском, хотя переводы в файлах .po и .mo присутствуют:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем-то другом дело - может, кеши. Я скачал украинский перевод woocommerce, сделал .mo файл через poedit, закинул .mo в \wp-content\languages\plugins\woocommerce-uk.mo. Все работает: http://take.ms/3YnWX

Comment: Перевод взял здесь: https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/stable/uk/default  (export внизу)

Comment: @KAGGDesign Спасибо! Помогло!

Answer (score 0):

У вас, похоже, несоответствие версии WooCommerce и перевода. Вот как выглядит текст в файле woocommerce-uk.po последней версии, скачанной с [официального сайта](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/stable/uk/default). Сравните с тем, что у вас на картинке.

Comment: Thank you bro! Действительно, проблема была в несоответствии перевода и версии WooCommerce. Скачал последнюю версию по ссылке, сделал .mo файл через poedit и закинул в \wp-content\languages\plugins\woocommerce-uk.mo Всё заработало.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый зеленой галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.